spreadsheet recognize my "time" input as "date"

This column (green) contain data with time format (HH.MM.SS),but for some reason, any time format with their minute below 12, converted into date format (probably because on date format, max month is 12), any minute over 12 works just fine.
that cell (the one i mark with blue square) supposed to be
19(HH).12(MM).58(SS)
but, it got converted into date (19/12/1958)
any idea how to stop this from happening? it keep happening all the time
Link to spreadsheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IKtSgeneUy5esKV9dIk_cEbMKm1vda5YpCqMo279k04/edit?usp=sharing

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

0:00:00=0=30/12/1899 0:00:00 and 19/12/1958 0:00:00=21,538 however your question isn't clear.  I don't know what you are doing, or why you have two duration formats or what "minute is below 12" means. [edit] your question for clarity and include 1. an example of your original data, 2. the specific change you are making to the specific cell (formula or manually)  3. The result you are getting 4. your expected result.

edited, sry english is not my native language, i wish you guys can understand

If you include a link to the spreadsheet we can probably figure it out.

i put the link guys, please help
